# api call working in one method but not working in another method ---TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript, rxjs

**Update 2:** Guys I used Kushpf answer that problem got solved...but now I am getting another...I think when I request I need to pass correct id...I even hardcoded but still I am getting errors..can you tell me how to fix it...

```
GET http://sports.com/Rats/color/black?RatId=20060&timestamp=1508039029859 404 (Not Found)
An error occurred Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1508039067018,"status":404,"error":"N…ssage available","path":"/Rats/color/black"}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers, …}
```

**Update 1:** I tried with Derek solution but still the same error happening..I printed out and saw self...in that I dont see sportsservice...is there any way I can fix it

**printed self values**

```
init {elemen: M.fn.init(1), _event: {…}, option: {…}, tabl: M.fn.init(1), wrappe: M.fn.init(1), …}
altRowTemplate:
ƒ ()
columns:
(13) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
content:
[div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable, prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: undefined]
dataSource:
init {option: {…}, _ma: {…}, _prefetc: {…}, _dat: init(21), _pristineDat: Array(21), …}
element:
[div#animals.contractPopupkGrid.k-grid.k-widget.k-reorderable, contex: div#animals.contractPopupkGrid.k-grid.k-widget.k-reorderable]
footer:
[prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: div#animals.contractPopupkGrid.k-grid.k-widget.k-reorderable, selecto: ".k-grid-footer"]
options:
{prefi: "", nam: "Grid", column: Array(13), toolba: null, autoBin: false, …}
pager:
init {elemen: M.fn.init(1), _event: {…}, option: {…}, dataSourc: init, linkTemplat: ƒ, …}
resizable:
init {elemen: M.fn.init(1), _event: {…}, option: {…}, orientatio: "horizontal", _positionMous: "x", …}
rowTemplate:
ƒ ()
scrollables:
(2) [div.k-grid-header-wrap.k-auto-scrollable, div.k-grid-content.k-auto-scrollable, prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: undefined]
selectable:
init {elemen: M.fn.init(1), _event: {…}, option: {…}, _marque: M.fn.init(1), _lastActiv: null, …}
table:
[table.k-selectable, prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: undefined]
tbody:
[tbody, prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: undefined]
thead:
[thead, prevObjec: M.fn.init(1), contex: undefined]
wrapper:
[div#animals.contractPopupkGrid.k-grid.k-widget.k-reorderable, contex: div#animals.contractPopupkGrid.k-grid.k-widget.k-reorderable]
_cellId:
"animals_active_cell"
_data:
(10) [init, init, init, init, init, init, init, init, init, init]
_draggableInstance:
init {elemen: M.fn.init(1), _event: {…}, option: {…}, _activate: false, userEvent: init, …}
_errorHandler:
ƒ ()
_events:
{dataBoun: Array(1)}
_group:
false
_groupableClickHandler:
ƒ (n)
_isMobile:
false
_muteRebind:
false
_progressHandler:
ƒ ()
_refreshHandler:
ƒ ()
_setContentWidthHandler:
ƒ ()
_size:
{widt: 960, heigh: 381}
__proto__:
r
```

- I am trying to learn angular and typescript.
- i am getting an error when I consume a new service.
- but when I consume another service through rxjs its not throwing the error.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing the relevant code below.
- whole code I will give it in gist since its big

**// error happening here
                        this.sportsservice.getResponse(vals, 'get', "")**

https://gist.github.com/texirv0203/e071a9ebea3a6aa0f8a0c65d47f75807

```or-tag-here
    $("#AnimalRatsGrid .RatNameFile").bind("click", function(e) {
      console.log("I am here");
       alert("I am here");
      //let params=values.selectedRow.sunDocID;
      //let url='http://sun.isports.com/PdfRatViewer.aspx?Ratid='+params+'&Ratsource=DISTRIBUTIONRat'

      kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);
      //let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+values.selectedRow.RatId;
                        let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+"7887878787";

                //let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+"233223232323";
                    this.sportsservice.getResponse(vals, 'get', "")
                                        .subscribe(data => {                     
                               //this.saveData(data, values.selectedRow.RatName);
                              //this.saveData(data, "untitled.txt");
                              var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

                             // var blob = Blob {"size": "11573", "type": "application/octet-stream"}

                             let fire = "untitled1.txt";
                              this.sportsservice.saveAs(blob,fire);

                                                //kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
                                        },
                                        err => { 
                             //kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
                             }
                        );




    });
```

**Error**

```or-tag-here
VM61482:27 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getResponse' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eval (animal.ts:427)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.js:4737)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-2.2.3.js:4549)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:236)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:6233)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:235)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:136)
at HTMLAnchorElement.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:304)
```

**No error in this method**

```or-tag-here
  public snakeRocket(values)
  {
    let grid = $("#AnimalRatsGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    let dataitem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    grid.dataSource.remove(dataitem);

    $("#divRocketAnimalRat").hide();

    let snakes = [
        { 
          "id": values.mainId,
          "RatDtos" : [{
            "RatId":dataitem.RatId,
            "RatName": dataitem.RatName,
            "RatType": dataitem.RatType,
            "RatData": this.encodeBase64,
            "notes": "",
            "notesId": 123,
            "sunDocID": 123,
            "url": "://localhost:1299/upload",
            "categoryType": "",
            "Timestamp": dataitem.date,
            "userID": dataitem.userID,
            "addedByName": dataitem.addedByName,
            "operationType": "Rocket",

            }]          
        } 
      ];

    this.sportsService.getResponse("player/color/Rat/", "post", snakes[0])
      .subscribe(data => {
          if (data.code === "S001") {
          } else {
          }
        },
        err => {
        }
      );

    $(".k-pager-numbers li").last().find("a").click();
  }
```

Comment: You probably need to fix you `this` reference - before  `this.sportsService.getResponse` console.log('this object', this); To see what it is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful about what `this` refers to:

In your second (working) example you are executing `this.sportservice.getResponse()` inside of a class context where the value of `this.sportservice` is set.

In your error example, however, you are executing `this.sportservice.getResponse()` inside a callback passed to `$().bind()` function.  This callback has a different context, and thus a different value of `this`.  You can read more about how `this` works [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript#what-is-this-in-javascript).

A simple solution would be to create a new reference to the `this` context you actually want to use.  For example:

```
var self = this;
$("#AnimalRatsGrid .RatNameFile").bind("click", function(e) {
  console.log("I am here");
   alert("I am here");
  //let params=values.selectedRow.sunDocID;
  //let url='http://sun.isports.com/PdfRatViewer.aspx?Ratid='+params+'&Ratsource=DISTRIBUTIONRat'

  kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), true);
  //let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+values.selectedRow.RatId;
                    let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+"7887878787";

            //let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+"233223232323";
                self.sportsservice.getResponse(vals, 'get', "")
                                    .subscribe(data => {                     
                           //this.saveData(data, values.selectedRow.RatName);
                          //this.saveData(data, "untitled.txt");
                          var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

                         // var blob = Blob {"size": "11573", "type": "application/octet-stream"}

                         let fire = "untitled1.txt";
                          self.sportsservice.saveAs(blob,fire);

                                            //kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
                                    },
                                    err => { 
                         //kendo.ui.progress($("#loading"), false);
                         }
                    );




});
```

Comment: Update: I tried with Derek solution but still the same error happening..I printed out and saw self...in that I dont see sportsservice...is there any way I can fix it

printed self values

Comment: @jajajaja what context is that whole function being run in?  Can you make sure the function exists on `this` there as well?

Answer (score 0):

Derek's explanation is right, but the place of declaring `var self = this;` is wrong.

As `this.sportsservice.getResponse` is called within `$("#AnimalRatsGrid .RatNameFile").bind("click", function(e) {` which itself is inside `dataBound: function(e) {`, you need to declare self outside it.

However, you have already declared a variable `let that = this;` which serves the exactly same purpose. So rather than using `this.sportsservice.getResponse`, use `that.sportsservice.getResponse`.

```
//let vals ="Rats/color/black?RatId="+"233223232323";
that.sportsservice.getResponse(vals, 'get', "")
    .subscribe(data => {
```

---

Also, consider renaming `that` to `self` throughout so that it becomes easier to understand for other developers (`self` is a common identifier used for this purpose)

Comment: that problem got solved...but now I am getting another...I think when I request I need to pass correct id...I even hardcoded but still I am getting errors..can you tell me how to fix it...

GET http://sports.com/Rats/color/black?RatId=20060&timestamp=1508039029859 404 (Not Found)
An error occurred Response {_body: "{"timestamp":1508039067018,"status":404,"error":"N…ssag

Comment: can you tell me why we need to declare outside databound function...can you explain...so that in future I won't face that problem..

Comment: Hey if I keep debugger inside subscribe method it's not going inside...any idea :(

Comment: You may check using logging. Please accept the answer if it helped.